# What is the solution for a 30 analog outputs sound card?

Tags: audio-interfaces, hardware, multichannel

I'm looking for a setup with 30 analog outputs sound card.

For now the only product I can see is the Motu 24io (2 of them), which seems to be out of date.

Any idea of another hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of any single units that will provide that many analog outs (but happy to be wrong) Also, FYI Motu have updated their product range recently so something like 2 x 16A's or 24Ao units could fit the bill

Comment: Spectro????????

Comment: Hi Mark ... well spotted ...

Comment: Good to see some more C74 forum users round here. Strangely enough I think EMV is also a Max user.

Answer (score 1):

Many professional external audio interfaces can be stacked or extended to get more inputs/outputs: RME, MOTU, Avid (Pro Tools HD), SSL, Apogee...

Some work by daisy chaining firewire or thunderbolt interfaces, others use a PCIe card with one of more dedicated digital multichannel interfaces that connect to rack hardware containing the analog inputs/outputs.

Comment: Any idea of good hardware that meet my requirements? Outside of the Motu brand? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you dislike Motu? All of these systems are a considerable investment, but all of them produce quality gear, with Motu being a bit cheaper than the rest (and arguably, the rest being of even higher quality).

Comment: Thanks, I was saying "outside of the Motu brand" because I already know their products.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a very solid 30 output system from RME using their MADI DA:

http://www.rme-audio.de/en/products/m32da.php

Not cheap though!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend paying attention to various **MADI** solutions.

For example, I highly recommend to see the RME's [MADI solutions](https://www.rme-audio.de/madi-solutions.html) in conjunction with an Ferrofish's [A32 AD/DA Converter](https://www.ferrofish.com/product/a32-madi-adat-converter/)

You can add and add new MADI expansion in the chain - up to 32x/64x/and more analog ports.